# knockout js foreach binding displays [object object]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I want to add an `<option>` for each item in my _areas array of type `KnockoutObservableArray<string>`. However when I do this:

```
<select 
            multiple="multiple"
            class="select-multiple"
            data-bind="foreach: _regionGetter._areas">
            <option data-bind="text: $data"></option>
        </select>
```

It prints out an `[object object]` inside each `<option>`. How do I get it to print the string in the array instead of [object object]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the items in your observable array are objects and then you are using `$data` so `[object object]` will be displayed. $data can only be used in this instance if the items were strings.

Instead change `<option data-bind="text: $data"></option>` to use the object property that contains the text that you want to be displayed.

For example if the objects had a property called `name` then you would bind the options text to this by using `<option data-bind="text: name"></option>`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tng1qhnp/)

Comment: Cheers. The observable array is of type string. I have no need to change it to be of type object, other than to give it named properties so that I can access them in my `forearch` data-binding. It seems like that will need to happen though and the `foreach` binding cannot be used on observable arrays of strings.

Comment: Can you please use the browser debug tools to verify that it is indeed a string? When I change it to a string your code works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/084um38L/)

Comment: I'm unsure how to use the debugger on html code. I only know how to use it on my javascript files. Which is half the battle, not being able to debug.

Comment: Can you use chrome and add a breakpoint where the areas are being set and then verify what it's set to. Here is some information on how to set a breakpoint: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en

Comment: My mistake, it was not a string. Thanks!